# Get all permutations of a slice

Tags: go, permutation

I was wondering if there was a way to find all the permutations of an slice filled with characters in Go?

In Python you can use `itertools.product` with a list or characters or integers, and you can get all the possible permutations.

I have looked to see if there is a package out there, and I cannot seem to find one. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: `itertools.product` gives you the Cartesian product of some sets.  It does *not* give you permutations.  Although you could use the Cartesian products to figure out the permutations, that would be horribly inefficient. http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: I am an idiot. I always get those mixed up, and I found a package for Cartesian products. Thanks

Comment: @Colum You made a mistake; that doesn't make you an idiot.

Comment: Depending on the size (and details) of your problem it might be
useful to take a look at Knuth, TAoCP vol. 4, chapter 7.2.1.2
(Sorry, no direct Go code here.)

Comment: [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), however, *does* give you permutations in Python.

Comment: @Colum So, what was the package you found for Cartesian products?  I think I'm looking for the same thing as you, and haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 11):

Permutations of anything implementing [`sort.Interface`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface): [Permutation{First,Next}](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/mathutil#PermutationFirst)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a implementation of a permutation function i've written...

https://github.com/itcraftsman/GoPermutation

```
func permutate(slice [][]int) (permutations [][][]int){
    f := fac(len(slice))
    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        elem, s := splice(slice, i)
        pos := 0
        for count := 0; count < (f / len(slice)); count++{
            if pos == (len(s) -1) {
                pos = 0
            }
            s = swap(s, pos, pos +1)
            permutation := make([][]int, len(slice))
            permutation = s
            permutation = append(permutation, elem)
            permutations = append(permutations, permutation)
            pos++
        } 
    } 
    return
}
```

it takes a 2D slice as input and returns a 3D slice, but you can easily change the code so that the function will take a simple slice as input and return a 2D slice with all permutations

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this answers your question but this is a simple recursive implementation to find the output below.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    values := [][]int{}

    // These are the first two rows.
    row1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    row2 := []int{4, 5, 6}
    row3 := []int{7, 8, 9}

    // Append each row to the two-dimensional slice.
    values = append(values, row1)
    values = append(values, row2)
    values = append(values, row3)


    fmt.Println(getPermutation(values))
}

func getPermutation(vids [][]int) [][]int {
    toRet := [][]int{}

    if len(vids) == 0 {
      return toRet
    }

    if len(vids) == 1 {
        for _, vid := range vids[0] {
            toRet = append(toRet, []int{vid})
        }
        return toRet
    }

    t := getPermutation(vids[1:])
    for _, vid := range vids[0] {
        for _, perm := range t {
            toRetAdd := append([]int{vid}, perm...)
            toRet = append(toRet, toRetAdd)
        }
    }

    return toRet
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/f8wktrxkU0

Output of above snippet:

```
[[1 4 7] [1 4 8] [1 4 9] [1 5 7] [1 5 8] [1 5 9] [1 6 7] [1 6 8] [1 6 9] [2 4 7] [2 4 8] [2 4 9] [2 5 7] [2 5 8] [2 5 9] [2 6 7] [2 6 8] [2 6 9] [3 4 7] [3 4 8] [3 4 9] [3 5 7] [3 5 8] [3 5 9] [3 6 7] [3 6 8] [3 6 9]]
```