Go: Iterate all possible combinations of elements in n arbitrary slices
Say we have a struct with n visible fields that are slices of arbitrary types and lengths:
var parameters := struct {
   Parameters1 []int
   Parameters2 []byte
   // ...
   ParametersN [][]byte
} {
   []int{1,2,4},
   []byte{0,1,2,3},
   //...
   [][]byte{[]byte("hi"), []byte("goodbye")}
}

How can we iterate it to obtain all possible combinations? Something like:
for combination in generateAllCombinations(parameters) {
   fmt.println(combination.Parameter1, combination.Parameter2, ..., combination.ParameterN)
}
//> 1, 0, ..., hi
//> 2, 0, ..., hi
//> 4, 0, ..., hi
//> 1, 1, ..., hi
//> ...

Ideally it should not precompute all the combinations, but rather iterate through them.

Are you looking for a Go solution (library or language feature) or a language-agnostic algorithm?

Building a generic of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22739674/1296707 should do the trick. Alternatively, at the end of the day, the input and output are both []any.

@Dave Go-specific solution.

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Parameters struct {
    Parameters1 []int
    Parameters2 []byte
    Parameters3 []string
    // so on
}

func unpackArray(s any) []any {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    r := make([]any, v.Len())
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        r[i] = v.Index(i).Interface()
    }
    return r
}

func (t Parameters) generateAllCombinations() {
    parameters := [][]any{}

    values := reflect.ValueOf(t)

    for i := 0; i < values.NumField(); i++ {
        value := values.Field(i).Interface()
        parameters = append(parameters, unpackArray(value))
    }

    generateCombinations(parameters, []interface{}{}, 0)
}

func generateCombinations(arrays [][]interface{}, prefix []interface{}, index int) {
    if index == len(arrays) {
        fmt.Println(prefix...)
        return
    }

    for _, element := range arrays[index] {
        generateCombinations(arrays, append(prefix, element), index+1)
    }
}

So in this code it first makes a 2D array of type any for all fields in struct using reflect.ValueOf to get all values of struct fields (You should be aware that all fields must be arrays; otherwise, type checking is necessary) then with unpackArray function it converts type any to array of any then with a simple recursive method if prints all combination of parmaeters.

It is a nice first approach, however it forces all the combinations to be computed ahead of time. The same way you don't compute an array of [100]int when running for i := range 100, it would be ideal to avoid computing all the options ahead of time.
